# Browser changing attribute translate="yes" to translate="translate"

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

We are using a translation library that is adding these two things to my page.

```
<html lang="en" class="notranslate translated-ltr">
<meta name="google" content="notranslate">
```

Because of that in-built browser translation is not working.
For specific div's we want to use browser translations as well.
When I add this line through inspect element

```
<div translate="yes">Some non-english Content</div>
```

It resolves the problem. But adding the same thing in my Vue 2 App, changes the added attribute value to

```
<div translate="translate">Some non-english Content</div>
```

And because of that, it is again not working. Can anyone help me in this case?

EDIT: We are on Vue 2.5.17 :(

Comment: `But adding the same thing in my Vue App` how are you doing that?

Comment: @Matt - works fine in that fiddle ...

Comment: Seems to be working fine in Vue3 but messing in Vue2

Comment: Vue2 2.6.14 is fine ... Vue 2.2.1 is not (as that was prior to the fix mentioned before)

Comment: I was looking at the vue2 version with 2.6.14 - I'm quite smart like that @Matt - you haven't posted a vue3 version

Comment: *We are on Vue 2* ... but what version of Vue 2 ... what is `Vue.version`?

Comment: update to the latest vue2 - 2.6.14

Comment: or at least something AFTER 2.6.11 where the problem was still present - since only 2.6.13 and 2.6.14 exist as releases after 2.6.11, best you get 2.6.14 - rather than the 3 year old version you're running now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading Vue from `2.5.17` to `2.6.14` resolved the issue. But this was breaking multiple functionality in the app.

Alternatively, DOM Manipulation resolved the issue without upgrading.

```
allowTranslation(){
            const messageContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.allowTranslate');
            messageContainer.forEach(box => {
                let allAttributes = [...box.attributes];
                if(!allAttributes.includes('translate')){
                    box.setAttribute('translate', 'yes')
                }
            })
        }
```